# Sending Message from G Sheet to Google Chat / Spaces

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-chat

This code works for sending text messages to Spaces but when I would like to send from the spreadsheet where I have added the app Script. The code I am using is:

```
function myFunction() {
    var WebWhooklink = "Sample_URL"
    var message = { text: "Hello"};
    var payload = JSON.stringify(message);
    var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            payload: payload
    };
  
    var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(WebWhooklink, options ).getContentText();
}
```

I have modified to below but the error shows up as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email");
var dataGrid = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 3, 3).getValues();  


    var WebWhooklink = "Sample_URL"
    var message = {dataGrid};
    var payload = JSON.stringify(message);
    var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            payload: payload
    };
  
    var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(WebWhooklink, options ).getContentText();
}
```

Error that comes:

> Exception: Request failed for https://chat.googleapis.com returned >code 400. Truncated server response: {
> "error": {
> "code": 400,

For Reference my Spreadsheet name is "Emailer" and range is as mentioned above and that is what I would like to send. I have tried multiple methods but it doesn't seem to send that range in the chat.

Attached is the spreadsheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gNGbwlCJW7Z0fjcJzMHrLsVH9c_v_dGTwYsF8Std9MA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share a sample data set? Always try including the minimal code needed to [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BryanMonterrosa I can share sample data set but you can use any sample data and range to illustrate an example. Just need to understand how it fits in correctly.

Comment: Got it. Regarding ```I have tried multiple methods but it doesn't seem to send that range in the chat```, could you share any of the methods that you already tried? You can share the code that is failing even if it doesn't work. 
That and an example of the desired output would help us a lot to understand the issue and try to get you a solution.

Comment: @BryanMonterrosa I have tried to show the original code and how I modified it to use to my context and the error I face. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: @BryanMonterrosa Unfortunately, it truncates all the entire range into a single row as text which is off, since I have a table. I have attached the required output here. It can be as a image as well and not necessarily a table.

Comment: Unfortunately Google Chat API doesn't seem to have a native option to send messages as tables, you would need to manipulate the object in order to get the desired output which goes outside the scope of the original question. Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464555/19602805. Otherwise I'd recommend you to open a new question focused on manipulating a ```message``` object.

Comment: @BryanMonterrosa I have modified my question to ensure it is comprehensive. Would appreciate the upvote since I am a newbie, it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error appears to indicate an issue with the `message` object:

> "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "dataGrid" at 'message': Cannot find field."

The documentation for this object indicates that it needs to include specific properties, for example, you can use `text` to send the values by passing `dataGrid.toString()`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email");
  var dataGrid = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 3, 3).getValues();

  var WebWhooklink = "Sample_URL"
  var message = { text: dataGrid.toString() }; // <- here
  var payload = JSON.stringify(message);
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(WebWhooklink, options).getContentText();
}
```

This object also provides more options like using [Cards](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/cards#Card_1).

---

#### Reference:

- Google Chat API - [Message resource](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages#Message)